# What is wrong with my query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to query the database using CursorLoader

this is the query that comes out from the loader

> 11-24 17:33:21.507: E/ACRA(32418): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, contact_id, photo_uri, data1,
>   lookup FROM view_data data WHERE (1) AND (( (mimetype=? OR mimetype=?)
>   AND data1 like ?%)) ORDER BY lookup

what is wrong near ")" that i don't see ?
- this is why my query arguments look like

```
Uri AUTO_COMPLETE_CONTACT_URI = Data.CONTENT_URI;

String[] AUTO_COMLETE_PROJECTION = {Data._ID, Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.PHOTO_URI,   Data.DATA1 ,Data.LOOKUP_KEY};
String AUTO_COMPLETE_SELECTION_LIKE_QUERY = AUTO_COMPLETE_SELECTION + " AND " + Data.DATA1 + " like ?";

public static String[] getAutoCompleteQuerySelectionArgs(String query) {
    return new String[] { Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, query+"%" };
}

/** This method is invoked by initLoader() */
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle data) {
    switch(id) {
    case ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_QUERY_ID:
        Uri uri = ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_CONTACT_URI;  
        if(data!=null) {
        String query = data.getString(ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_QUERY);
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getBaseContext(), uri, ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMLETE_PROJECTION, ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_SELECTION_LIKE_QUERY , Query.getAutoCompleteQuerySelectionArgs(query), ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_SORT_ORDER); 
        }else {
            return  new CursorLoader(getActivity().getBaseContext(), uri, ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMLETE_PROJECTION, ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_SELECTION , null, ContactsQuery.AUTO_COMPLETE_SORT_ORDER);
        }
    }
return null;
}

/** This method is executed in ui thread, after onCreateLoader() */
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) { 
    chipsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(c);       
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    chipsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: FROM view_data data check there should be only table name

Comment: Without trying out the code, I'd say, that the problem is with your `like` part of the query - you should have `'` around the right-hand side of the `like`. An example `data1 like '?%'`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Arju Absolutely unnecessary, but `FROM` is correct: you may use [`FROM table-name table-alias`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#single-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LIKE pattern does not use correct SQL syntax.

The `%` must be inside a string (i.e., inside quotes), but the `?` must be outside, so you have to concatenate them:

```
... AND data1 LIKE ? || '%')) ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Also, the from clause is malformed as pointed out by a commenter above.

Comment: @EricTobias Absolutely unnecessary, but `FROM` is correct: you may use [`FROM table-name table-alias`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#single-source).

Comment: indeed this is correct, i needed to do query + "%" for it to work

Comment: @LS_dev While you are right and the syntax is accepted, I would argue that it is correct as by the ISO norm. I quote: _The AS clause is the syntax defined in the ISO standard for assigning a name to a result set column. This is the preferred syntax to use in SQL Server 2005._ from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179300.aspx. While I am aware they refer to SELECT rather than the FROM statement, I would argue that consistency is key and well written code is more important than syntactical shortcuts!

Comment: @EricTobias I, myself, always use `AS` to enhance legibility. However "malformed" as you applied was incorrect, as syntax used is absolutely legal.

Comment: @LS_dev I never implied the syntax was incorrect. I apologise for my informal use of _malformed_ which should have read _formatted badly_. Thank you for pointing that out!