# using "like" with dblite, nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite

http://webreflection.blogspot.jp/2013/07/dblite-sqlite3-for-nodejs-made-easy.html

dblite is a great module for sqlite in use with nodejs.
however, i cant seem to get "like" keyword" working.

```
db.query(
'SELECT *,rowid FROM song__tv WHERE song LIKE %?%',
[rTitle],
function (rows) {
    console.log("===post===");
    console.log(rows.length);
    console.log(rows[0]);

res.render("tv_page", {pagename: "tv_page", posts: rows,title:rTitle})
}
);//query
```

what seems to be the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176467/what-is-wrong-with-my-query)

Comment: What I see is that you select *,rowid  which I don't know if this works as * already selects all columns and [rTitle] if it's not a variable should be ['rTitle'] because only numbers may be entered without quotes